# displaying in EditText in multiple lines

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-edittext

i'm trying to display a row in dataBase in the `EditBox` . But i am having problems.
so far my code is

```
public void ViewEmployeeButton (View view)
{
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Employee e1 = new Employee();       
    EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
    EditText detailEmp=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.detailEmployee);
    int id=Integer.getInteger(et.getText().toString());
    e1=db.getEmployee(id);
    detailEmp.setText(???)
}
```

employee have functions of `Getid, GetName, GetUsername, GetPassowrd, GetAge` which will return the `Strings`.
now what to write in the parameters of `setText`?
so that the outout is in Multiple lines.

in database the Row is like:

1 kiran password KiranTauqir 21

i want the output like

id 1
username kiran
password password
Name KiranTauqir
Age 21

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just retrieve all the column values and append them to a String along with new line character :  "\n".

Sample Code may look like this :

```
    int i=0;
    String output;
    while(i<e1.getColumnCount())
    {
           output.append(e1.getString(i) +"\n");   //getString(i) will return the value of particular column
           i++;
    }
    detailEmp.setText(output);
```